# An archimedean analogue of the non-canonicity of Hodge--Tate decomposition

Tags: hodge-theory, p-adic-hodge-theory

For smooth proper schemes over $\mathbb{C}_p$, there is no canonical Hodge--Tate decomposition (but [there is](https://mathoverflow.net/a/96907/138661) something close). Is there an analogue of this on the archimedean side? I thought about this a little bit but did not arrive anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

See Example 4.1.2 in the notes of Brinon--Conrad. There is something similar going on there: for a smooth proper scheme over complex numbers there is a functorial splitting of the Hodge filtration, but for an arbitrary field of characteristic 0 there is only an exhaustive and separated filtration whose associated graded
vector space is the Hodge cohomology (and it does not admit a functorial splitting, generally speaking).